# How to share java dependencies from maven environment to non-maven environment

Tags: maven

I have two servers.

On first server, maven is installed and in second server maven is not installed.

My kafka cluster is accessible via second server.

But the kafka libraries can be imported via maven only on first server. How do I migrate these libraries to second server?

Should I export each library as a jar via maven in first server and then place these jars on second servers?

Comment: RUN command `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies` then you can find all jar file in the `target/dependency` directory.

Comment: I see you have previous questions about Python, so how do you distribute your Python dependencies to external servers that may not have access to run pip? Why treat Java differently?

Answer (score 1):

I have no details about your setup, but it sounds strange to me that you mix what I understand are productive environments (what you call "servers" here, you may like to clarify) and build toolchain in the same question.

Whatever your software is, you have no obligation to run and build it in the same place - actually, the further those 2 places are, the better.  My proposal is that you set up different and isolated environments:

- Build/CI environment: some jenkins, buildkite agent, gitlab CI agent, whatever you like, that builds deliverables upon branches of your code. Those deliverables are built, e.g. with maven, and stored somewhere (an S3 bucket, folder in ftp server, an artifactory, nexus, whatever).  Ofc there is no kafka or any other productive software in this environment.
- Dev, staging, prod, whatever you call them, environments, built upon some template.  These need no toolchain but they need whatever runtime you need for your application.  You can build regular machines with chef or something like that, or set up a container manager and use your CI to build container images of your software.

Source code should never be in your productive servers, so you need not maven there - the compiled deliverable will be deployed there in whatever form suits you (jar, ear, container image, whatever) by some tool of your choice.

I am aware that this does not give you a straight answer to a maven juggling question, but I think this kind of setup will bring you much further.

Answer (score 0):

Your "non Maven connected" environment doesn't need "Maven" (in quotes because Gradle and sbt could be interchanged here).  It, like all JVM environments, needs a `CLASSPATH`, including JARs and classes for dependency code.

You should use [Maven Assembly plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html) to build what is know as an uber/fat JAR, and distribute that.

Or, mentioned in other answer, you can do the same, but using Docker images as your distributable archive, perhaps using [Jib Maven Plugin](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/tree/master/jib-maven-plugin).